# Extremely slow connection on LAN for Readynas NV+ v2 NAS

Tags: linux, networking, readynas

I am experiencing extremely slow upload rates on a Readynas NV+v2 NAS.

### Speed measurement

When testing using [`speedtest-cli`](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) I get the following result:

```
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 165.95 Mbits/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 0.80 Mbits/s
```

I was expecting 300/300 on this line, and this is what I am getting on other devices connected to the same router.

- When I am measuring the NAS to Internet I am getting results around
  150 Mbps down, 0.5 Mbps up.
- When I am measuring the NAS to another device connected to the Zyxel
  through WiFi the speeds are OK (measured with `iperf`), around 250
  Mbps/250 Mbps.
- When I am running `speedtest-cli` from another device connected to
  the Linksys I am getting speeds around 300/300.

### Settings of eth0 and other information

**Network setup:**
Fibre -> Media converter CTSystem HET-3012 -> Zyxel P-2812 Router -> Linksys E3000 as switch-> NAS

```
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Link detected: yes

root@nas:~# uname -a
Linux nas 2.6.31.8.nv+v2 #1 Thu Apr 18 17:40:54 HKT 2013 armv5tel GNU/Linux 

root@nas:~# lshw -class network* -
network 
description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 3
logical name: eth0
serial: x size: 1GB/s
capacity: 1GB/s
capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 
1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=mv_eth 
driverversion=KW_LSP_5.1.3_patch18 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.41 link=yes
multicast=yes port=MII speed=1GB/s
```